# Extended hash wants to load itself from YAML

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm making a class that's intended to be an intelligent Hash that knows how to load its own values if given a YAML filename and then perform various operations on them. Except that first step is stumping me. Given this code:

```
    class Agent < Hash
        def initialize
            super
        end

        def load_from_file(filename)
            if (File.file?(filename)) 
                self = YAML.load_file(filename)
            end
        end
    end
```

...the error message is that one "Can't change the value of self"

How would you make a hash that loads itself from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Rather than the self assignment, you just want to use [Hash#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace):

```
class Agent < Hash
    def initialize
      super
    end

    def load_from_file(filename)
      if (File.file?(filename))
        replace YAML.load_file(filename)
      end
    end
end
```

`#replace` replaces the keys and values of the calling hash with they keys and values from the passed hash - exactly what you want in this case. However, be sure that you validate that the YAML data is indeed a `Hash` before calling `#replace`.